# Office communicator voice chat

Tags: ms-office-communicator

My company recently mandated a switch from Skype to Office Communicator for IM / voice chat.

While Skype was never the be all and end all of VOIP, it was at least usable.

With Communicator, if one person is talking, everyone else is basically silent (or as good as) so a normal conversation is impossible.

No one can interrupt anyone else, if two people start talking at once it's a crap shoot who gets to be heard and often the person who is inaudible doesn't know it.

There do not seem to be any client side settings to fix this.  Is there anything that can be done server side or is it just rubbish?

Comment: We're having none of those problems at all (global rollout with over 15k+ users). Definitely a config issue for you. Can't advise further as OCS isn't my baby

Comment: What back end infrastructure is Office Communicator working off - this sort of multi-party voice conferencing works very well on all the OCS 2007 environments I've installed, the one thing that stands out OCS is the voice quality is excellent even over relatively poor networks.

Answer (score 1):

We use OCs in this manner and it works excellent.

To see if your network/server you could use the free UCTrial from Microsoft to test:
http://windowspbx.blogspot.com/2009/12/get-free-hosted-microsoft-office.html

We've been OCS and the videoconferencing work excellent for us. (i interupt all the time! ;-)